# String to int to answer what move to do

Tags: c#, indexing

Hey I am stuck with a problem. I want to parse a string into a integer because I am making a console game where the player should choose which move to use. So far I defined the parse but I can't seem to find out how I would iterate over my list to see if the move is actually valid. I have a list called Move where each pokemon has its own elemental but how would I reference this here is the code

```
List<Move> FireMoves = new List<Move>();

FireMoves.Add(new Move("Ember"));
FireMoves.Add(new Move("Fireblast"));

List<Move> WaterMoves = new List<Move>();

WaterMoves.Add(new Move("Bubble"));
WaterMoves.Add(new Move("Bite"));

List<Move> GrassMoves = new List<Move>();

GrassMoves.Add(new Move("Cut"));
GrassMoves.Add(new Move("Megadrain"));
GrassMoves.Add(new Move("Razor Leaf"));
```

Here is the other part. The last two lines I think it's right but I don't get how I would make the console understand that when 1 is pressed move no 1 is used

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Pokemon
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Move> FireMoves = new List<Move>();

            FireMoves.Add(new Move("Ember"));
            FireMoves.Add(new Move("Fireblast"));

            List<Move> WaterMoves = new List<Move>();

            WaterMoves.Add(new Move("Bubble"));
            WaterMoves.Add(new Move("Bite"));

            List<Move> GrassMoves = new List<Move>();

            GrassMoves.Add(new Move("Cut"));
            GrassMoves.Add(new Move("Megadrain"));
            GrassMoves.Add(new Move("Razor Leaf"));

            List<Pokemon> roster = new List<Pokemon>();


            // INITIALIZE YOUR THREE POKEMONS HERE
            //Tilføj moves 
            roster.Add(new Pokemon("Charmander", 3, 52, 50, 39, Elements.Fire,FireMoves));
            roster.Add(new Pokemon("Squirtle", 2, 48, 65, 44, Elements.Water, WaterMoves));
            roster.Add(new Pokemon("Bulbasaur", 3, 49, 49, 45, Elements.Grass, GrassMoves));

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the world of Pokemon!\nThe available commands are list/fight/heal/quit");

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nPlese enter a command");
                switch (Console.ReadLine())
                {
                    case "list":
                        // PRINT THE POKEMONS IN THE ROSTER HERE
                        Console.WriteLine("These are the pokemons that are currently active");
                        foreach(Pokemon g in roster)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(roster.IndexOf(g)+" "+g.Name);
                        }
                        break;

                    case "fight":
                        //PRINT INSTRUCTIONS AND POSSIBLE POKEMONS (SEE SLIDES FOR EXAMPLE OF EXECUTION)
                        Console.Write("Choose who you should fight against and the pokemon you want to control is mentionened last\n");
                        Console.Write("To chose your pokemon is mentioned first example of 'Charmander Squirtle', where Squirtle is the opponent\n");                       
                        //Console.Write("1=Charmander vs Squirtle\n2=Squirtle vs Charmander\n3=Charmander vs Bulbasaur\n4=Bulbasaur vs Squirtle\n5=Bulbasaur vs Charmander\n6=Squirtle vs Bulbasaur\n");

                        //READ INPUT, REMEMBER IT SHOULD BE TWO POKEMON NAMES
                        string input = Console.ReadLine();
                        //BE SURE TO CHECK THE POKEMON NAMES THE USER WROTE ARE VALID (IN THE ROSTER) AND IF THEY ARE IN FACT 2!

                        List<String> inputs = new List<string>(input.Split(" ".ToCharArray()));

                        //BE SURE TO CHECK THE POKEMON NAMES THE USER WROTE ARE VALID (IN THE ROSTER) AND IF THEY ARE IN FACT 2!
                        Pokemon player = null;
                        Pokemon enemy = null;
                        foreach (Pokemon p in roster)
                        {
                            if (inputs[0] == p.Name)
                            {
                                player = p;
                            }
                            if (inputs[1] == p.Name)
                            {
                                enemy = p;
                            }


                        }
                        //if everything is fine and we have 2 pokemons let's make them fight
                        if (player != null && enemy != null && player != enemy)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("A wild " + enemy.Name + " appears!");
                            Console.Write(player.Name + " I choose you! ");

                            //BEGIN FIGHT LOOP
                            while (player.Hp > 0 && enemy.Hp > 0)
                            {
                                //PRINT POSSIBLE MOVES

                                Console.Write("What move should we use?\n");
                                foreach(Pokemon p in roster) {

                                    if (player.Name == p.Name)

                                        foreach (Move n in p.Moves)
                                        {

                                        Console.WriteLine(p.Moves.IndexOf(n)+" "+n.Name);

                                        }
                             }
                                //GET USER ANSWER, BE SURE TO CHECK IF IT'S A VALID MOVE, OTHERWISE ASK AGAIN
                                string moveInput = Console.ReadLine();
                                int moveNo = int.Parse(moveInput);

                                int move = -1;

                                //CALCULATE AND APPLY DAMAGE
                                int damage = -1;

                                //print the move and damage
                                Console.WriteLine(player.Name + " uses " + player.Moves[move].Name + ". " + enemy.Name + " loses " + damage + " HP");

                                //if the enemy is not dead yet, it attacks
                                if (enemy.Hp > 0)
                                {
                                    //CHOOSE A RANDOM MOVE BETWEEN THE ENEMY MOVES AND USE IT TO ATTACK THE PLAYER
                                    Random rand = new Random();
                                    /*the C# random is a bit different than the Unity random
                                     * you can ask for a number between [0,X) (X not included) by writing
                                     * rand.Next(X) 
                                     * where X is a number 
                                     */
                                    int enemyMove = -1;
                                    int enemyDamage = -1;

                                    //print the move and damage
                                    Console.WriteLine(enemy.Name + " uses " + enemy.Moves[enemyMove].Name + ". " + player.Name + " loses " + enemyDamage + " HP");
                                }
                            }
                            //The loop is over, so either we won or lost
                            if (enemy.Hp <= 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(enemy.Name + " faints, you won!");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(player.Name + " faints, you lost...");
                            }
                        }
                        //otherwise let's print an error message
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalid pokemons");
                        }
                        break;

                    case "heal":
                        //RESTORE ALL POKEMONS IN THE ROSTER

                        Console.WriteLine("All pokemons have been healed");
                        break;

                    case "quit":
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Unknown command");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: int.TryParse() and ask user again if it's not an int or a valid move.

Comment: Are you just looking for `p.Moves[moveNo]`? You won't be able to do this outside of that for loop unless you decide on what pokemon to use too

Comment: I think, for this task you should use finite state machine rather than creating yet-another-own-concept. Every game uses it for validation and state changing, and it fits your case perfectly. More here: http://gamedevelopertips.com/finite-state-machine-game-developers/

Comment: Can you add your Move object to the post? I'm guessing that it has _name, _damage as properties for the move Object. I suspect you may not have a getter in your object that you can reference.

Comment: I have a getter havent touched move it is an assignment I am sure it is right my teacher wrote it xd It is just a simple constructor with the name of the move and only has a getter no setter

Comment: Any specific reason you are parsing to a dead variable? You have string MoveInput and int moveNo, but then later you declare an int move = -1; but never use the MoveNo... https://puu.sh/D6yUl/7799dbd28e.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to iterate only through the player moves. Since the choice has been made

```
for (int i = 0; i < player.Moves.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i + " " + player.Moves[i].Name);
}
```

> "to see if the move is actually valid" and "I dont get how I would make the console understand that when 1 is pressed move no 1 is used"

any **positive** move number that is **smaller** then the amount of items in your list is a valid input. If you present the user the index as choice then you can use the index to access the item/move.

```
if(moveNo >= 0 && moveNo < player.Moves.Count)
{
    //access move by index
    var move = player.Moves[moveNo]
}
else
{
    // not a valid move
}
```

Comment: But I cant reference it inside the foreach statement so i cant use p.moves how would i go around this? I edited posted full snippet

Comment: how do you intend to make the player move? how is she supposed to decide which pokemon to take? you don't ask for it. you will have multiple choices with the same index `0` for each Pokemon. You need to solve this

Comment: Player chooses the pokemon by writing for instance "Charmander Bulbasaur" and then the player gets told a wild bulbasaur appears you are Charmander which move you want to use 0, 1 , 2 outside of the foreach statement but in the same case where I made the commen //get user input

Comment: you itenrate over the entire `roster` and print out all moves. How many items are in the `roster` ? only 1 ? if there are move you will have multiple choices with the same index

Comment: I have 3 pokemons in the roster but I cant go into the foreach loop to reference by using p.moves so I need another way I am not allowed to do it like that. I have to read the user input after the pokemon is chosen when the fight begins to know which move the user wants to use but I cant get my head around atm. My list with roster is the pokemons i have and the list of moves is divided into elementel 3 in total but how can this be referenced in a way were everything is taking into consideration since we dont know which pokemon the player will chose

Comment: @Jerry actually you need to show only the `player` moves, since the user has decided which pokemon to choose. So he cannot use the moves of any other pokemon, am I right?=! then you would choose from the `player.Moves` collection. I edited my post, have a look

Comment: I think we are on the right track but it prints me pokemon.move and not the name of the attack i am using ur if statement no loop

Comment: @Jerry: Looking at the problem, you are really going to have to separate your code (and thought process) more if you want to be able to break this down into smaller problems. Selecting which Pokémon are entering battle has nothing to do (from a gameplay/code perspective) with giving an attack command to a pokémon that is in battle. We shouldn't need to know/care about how you initiate a battle to answer a question related to what happens during a battle.

Comment: @Jerry I don't print anything in the if statement. You probably forgot to print the `.Name` property. do you have `player.Moves[moveNo].Name` ? or only `player.Moves[moveNo]` ? in the Console.WriteLine command

Comment: Thanks @Mong Zhu that fixed my problem! :D

Answer (score 1):

I think the real answer here is not so much how you iterate, but how you should've designed your move class to work. Whil you could ignore the design flaw now and work around it, it's much better to fix it now and do it the right way from the start.

I'm going to address issues that you may not have been facing now, but they are better examples of why your design is flawed, and they will become issues if you're building a Pokémon style game.

### **The problem**:

```
roster.Add(new Pokemon("Charmander", 3, 52, 50, 39, Elements.Fire, FireMoves));
```

Here, you say that Charmander is a `Elements.Fire` type, and has a certain `List<Move>`.

However, the application has no way of knowing whether these are moves that Charmander can actually perform. What is stopping me from doing:

```
roster.Add(new Pokemon("Charmander", 3, 52, 50, 39, Elements.Fire, WaterMoves));
```

**To you**, this doesn't look like an issue right now. You can read the name of the list, so its type is defined, right? Since you're responsible for adding this list to the pokémon's moveset, you know you're doing the right thing. Right?

So let's imagine that when your application gets bigger, you have the following method:

```
public void PerformAttack(Move move, Pokemon attacker, Pokemon defender)
{

}

// Example

PerformAttack(ember, charmander, bulbasaur);
```

Because Bulbasaur is a grass type, he takes extra damage from fire attacks. But how do we know that the chosen move is actually a fire move? **Without the context of the list it is stored in, you have no way of knowing if a certain move is of a certain type**. (And you can't use `attacker.Type` because if Charmander performs a Normal attack, Bulbasaur does not take extra damage from that since Bulbasaur does not have a weakness to Normal attacks).

You have nothing in place to check if a Pokémon is able to perform the move it is told to do, and you have nothing in place to check if a Pokémon has a certain weakness/resistance to certain moves. These are essential elements of the Pokémon games that you are going to run into sooner rather than later, but your design is making it impossible to do this.

This all comes from a bad design decision in the `Move` class: **moves don't have a type**. To combat this, you've tried to name your lists:

```
List<Move> FireMoves = new List<Move>();
List<Move> WaterMoves = new List<Move>();
List<Move> GrassMoves = new List<Move>();
```

---

### **The solution:**

Move must have a type of its own:

```
public class Move
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Elements Type { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you can fix all the problems I showcased. All you have to do is set up the type when you create the move:

```
List<Move> FireMoves = new List<Move>();
FireMoves.Add(new Move("Ember", Elements.Fire));

List<Move> WaterMoves = new List<Move>();
WaterMoves .Add(new Move("Bubble", Elements.Water));
```

This also means that you no longer need to have separate type-based lists, you can have one big list.

```
List<Move> Moves = new List<Move>();
Moves.Add(new Move("Ember", Elements.Fire));
Moves.Add(new Move("Bubble", Elements.Water));
```

And because all moves are now part of the same list, your question becomes much easier to answer:

> So far I defined the parse but I cant seem to find out how I would iterate over my list to see if the move is actually valid.

```
public bool IsMove(Pokemon target, string userCommand)
{
    return target.Moves.Any(move => move.Name.ToLower() == userCommand.ToLower());
}
```

Which you can then use like this:

```
string userCommand = Console.ReadLine();

if(IsMove(userCurrentPokemon, userCommand))
{
    // Handle attack logic
}
else
{
    // Handle non-attack logic
}
```

Note that if you still want to have separate lists for a particular reason, you can still filter the move list:

```
var fireMoves = Moves.Where(move => move.Type == Elements.Fire).ToList();
var waterMoves = Moves.Where(move => move.Type == Elements.Water).ToList();
var grassMoves = Moves.Where(move => move.Type == Elements.Grass).ToList();
```

---

*If anyone wishes to comment that this answer is focusing on existing Pokémon features rather than OP's game: that is correct, but I chose to approach it this way because OP is workig in this context. I could've given a more neutral "add a property instead of naming a variable" example, but that's not as easy to understand, and I'm inferring that OP is a beginner to the field of programming who may struggle with independently implementing an overly generalized answer.*

Comment: I see your point but I have enums which represents the elements would that still be the same if i changed it?

Comment: @Jerry If you changed _what_ exactly? To no longer using enums? You'd always be able to make it work, you simply need to make sure that both pokémon and moves have a type defined (enum or not) so you can then use it for your combat logic. It's technically not every required to use the _same_ enum for pokémon and moves, but if you use separate enums (or other approaches) you're going to end up having to create a mapping between them in order to get your combat logic working. Since pokémon works with a fixed element list that applies to pokemon and moves, I would suggest you stick with that.